# How to get the query string url in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend

I created a custom post template that displays the post according to the taxonomy and terms.

The url that i created looks like this : http://example.com/courses/course-title/?type=english-test&term=new

There is an example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) add_query_arg() but it seems that it is retrieving the values statically

```
// This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar'
   echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' ) );

// This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar&baz=tiny'
$arr_params = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'tiny' );
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( $arr_params ) );
```

**Question:** How can i get the **english-test** and **new** from the url and store them to a variable?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not 100% clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can able to retrieve the values as GET parameters.

Use this:

```
$variable = $_GET['param_name'];

//Or as you have it
$type = $_GET['type'];
$term = $_GET['term'];

echo $type; // english-test
echo $term; // new
```

Comment: You should sanitize your code. **NEVER EVER** use any non sanitized values from `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. This is the most common place used by hackers to inject malicious code into your site. **SANITIZE SANITIZE  SANITIZE**